# CSS selector for the text inside a button

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add a css to show/hide the text inside a button taking into account that the inner structure of the button contains as well an icon that we do not want to hide ?

```
<button>
 <span class="..."><svg><path d="...."></path></svg></span>
 Reset
 <span class="..."></span>
</button>
```

cssRule that is able to behave as removing the 'Reset' text inside the button, changing the button box size accordingly

Comment: Technically, you can set `button { color: transparent; }` and then `button > * { color: black; }` (or whatever color you need it to be) but you're probably better off wrapping the text in a `span` and hiding that instead

Comment: @vrugtehagel , thanks I've no control on how the button is rendered, we want to make it smaller as well taking less space.  I think it's impossible, but who knows..

Comment: It's not impossible, I just gave you a solution - I just felt I should add that that's not generally a good solution if you _do_ have control over the markup (because you're resetting the color, causing `color` to no longer be inherited).

Comment: setting the button transparent is not changing the button box size, this is also needed, thanks nonetheless

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, apologies. It's still possible, but a bit harder; you can use `display: grid;` on the button combined with `grid-template: auto / auto 0 auto;`. This should cause the text to take up no space. Then you can combine this with my previous suggestion and voila!

Comment: @vrugtehagel , that's a smart one , thanks.

Comment: @vrugtehagel , doesn't look as working. Eventually font-size: 0px works as a charm.